# Filter relevant search results SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

I had a 5 word documents Test1, Test 2, test 3, test 4 and test 5 and i had variant, score, geoname and complex variant like the below.

Test 1

Variant : 501
Score : 500
GoeName : 502

Test 2

Variant : 500
Score : 502
GoeName : 501

Test 3

Variant : 502
Score : 501
GoeName : 500

Test 4

Variant : 602
Score : 601
GoeName : 600
Complex variant : 500

Test 5

Variant : 500
Score : 700
GoeName : 701
Complex variant : 600

I uploaded all those files in document library and crawled the documents. when i search for variant : 500 using search box instead of getting Test 2 word document which matches exactly what i typed in the search box it is pulling test 4 document. which has Complex variant : 500 in it.

How can i get relevant search results??

If i search for variant: 500 i should get Test 2 and Test 5 document.
If i search for Complex variant : 500 then i should get Test 4 document.

Comment: Try replacing the ":" with "=", that way you request only absolute matches on the property. Also remove blanks before and after the equal sign

Comment: Even after searching using '=' instead of ':' i am getting the same results. I searched for variant=500. I get document Test 4 which has "Complex variant : 500" text in it. There is another document Test 2 which has exact match "variant : 500". I want Test2 to show up first and rest later.

Comment: Do you really have a managed property for "variant" and is "variant" really the name of that managed property? If you have no managed property, your search is really not scoped to your field at all, but does a free text search

Comment: so to accomplish it. i have to manually create site column to the document library and while uploading the document i have to give the variant values to that columns and then when i search the documents with variants..i should get the exact match right ???

Comment: well if you also make sure a managed property is created in the search service application for your column, then yes